# Is it possible to create a background app using node-webkit?

Tags: background-process, node-webkit, tray

I wanted to create a complete background running app that only shows up in the system-tray and doesn't have any "window" as such. I tried setting the "window" attribute to false, but that doesn't work. Is there any way to create a completely background daemon-style application using node-webkit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use this package.json

```
{
  "window": {
    "show": false
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. Has it been depreciated?

Comment: @Taurian - Not deprecated. Maybe you're just doing something wrong, like not opening your window with nw.gui perhaps?

Comment: Can you elaborate this>

Comment: does not work, a hide window canot render content, example: youtube in background.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally place a `tray` to truly reflect a background app:

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Tray